# unable to load static file in spring 4

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Hi I am trying to load the jquery file in jsp but getting 404
Find below the project structure
[image]

I have configured the following in configuration too

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "common.spring.controller" })
public class WebConfig {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        //viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/");
    }

}
```

below is how i include file in jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/jsFiles/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Dono why its not working.

**UPDATE:** I am able to see the resources folder under **target/project snapshot/resources** but getting 404 for url

```
http://localhost:8080/resources/jsfiles/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
```

directly hitting below Url didnt work either

```
http://localhost:8080/Sample/resources/jsfiles/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
```

Comment: Have you tried not including the `/resources` part in the script tag?

Comment: @csmckelvey you mean src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js" that didnt work

Comment: No I meant just remove `/resources`, not `/resources/jsFiles`. Not sure if it will work but it is easy to try.

Comment: @csmckelvey nope didnt work.

Comment: So you have tried all of these? `/resources/jsFiles/jquery-3.3.1.min.js`, `/jsFiles/jquery-3.3.1.min.js`, `jsFiles/jquery-3.3.1.min.js`, `/jquery-3.3.1.min.js`, and `jquery-3.3.1.min.js`

Comment: yup didnt work.

Comment: is your resources folder marked as resource root?

Comment: your resources is not in classpath but in web resources. Try this config `registry.addResourceHandler("resources/**").addResourceLocations(new String[] { "resources/" });`

Comment: @angelo not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally was able to resolve the issue

removing `addResourceHandlers` method and including the below code did the trick

```
@Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configure) {
    configure.enable();

    }
```

in jsp i used the include like below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jsFiles/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```